# Convert Print CSS to Screen CSS

Tags: css

I have an html document with css styling, that is converted directly to PDF via PrinceXml. Due to this, the entire css file makes use of pt and not px.

However, we now have a requirement to use the same html document and allow users to view it on screen, but this (I assume) necessitates the use of px isntead of pt.

Is there some formula that we could use that could approximate the conversion? Just eye-balling it looks like multiplying all the pts by 1.5 would get us to more or less the right result. It doesn't have to be exact.

Or should be just code up a separate stylesheet specifically for screen instead?

Edit: For clarity. The text is already all expressed in ems. Its the margins, padding and border weights that are currently in pts.

Comment: Well, in all honesty in 2013 you should really be using `em` for text sizes on web pages.

Comment: `pt` is actually fine unit to use for `screen` devices. See [font units](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html) for more info. Also, [here's a good chart for converting pt to px](http://reeddesign.co.uk/test/points-pixels.html)

Comment: The text is 99% ems. Its mostly the margins, padding and border weights that need converting

Comment: @BenM pt is directly related to em. No need to use em instead of pt. But in general, you're right. Using relative sizes is better than using absolute pixel sizes. Probably no need to convert anything.

Comment: Updated original question to state that the measurements are for margins, padding and border weights, not text.